# How to share python and selenium exe files

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, exe, pyinstaller

I have converted a python file with seleniumto an exe using pyinstaller using [this guide](https://www.zacoding.com/en/post/python-selenium-to-exe/). I have followed the steps and have one singular exe file in the dist folder of my main project folder. My question is, how would I share this file because doesn't it depend on having selenium installed? What about the build folder in the main directory? Someone who has experience with this type of thing please can you help. I can answer any further questions in the comments, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `import` statements in your script, PyInstaller automatically detects the modules imported and include them to the compiled EXE. It can detect a lot of modules, and selenium is between them ([full list](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Supported-Packages))